# Функция unity GetContacts(hit) всегда возвращает 0

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
pc = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();  //коллайдер самого игрового объекта
 hit = new Collider2D[10];
bool isHit = false;
int x= pc.GetContacts(hit);
if (x > 0) {

} else {
    //все время 0
}
```

Обидно что все работало, но я игрался с камерой и физикой и теперь не работает.Вот картинки моих нынешних настроек. В Layer Collision Matrix галочки не трогал. Игра 2д, но я хотел туда 3д модель впихнуть, поэтому с камерой и физикой игрался потому что не отображала 3д модель.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: к]

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в том что в Edit/ProjectSettings/Time Time Scale был 0. Я туда не лазил, не знаю почему он изменился. Это решение проблемы.